# how to search books when user can search partial names or do spelling mistakes in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, spring-boot

I am providing a web based search to the users of a book store. The user can enter book title, author or ISBN in a single field. The search is having issues like it's not searching if given wrong spelling in a title (Book name) e.g. If searched for "People of America" it will search perfect but "The People of The America" or "Peopl of Amreka" or "People America" won't give me accurate results.

I am calling the queries through Spring Boot java application and as a hack i am doing it in 3 phases. If the first query has 0 results then i move to second and if second has 0 results then i move to third.

I have been trying things like pattern matching and pg_trgm (Postgres trigrams) but as didn't succeeded. Any help will be highly appreciated.

First query is :

```
    select distinct * from (select title, author, publisher, isbn, edition, 
      book_type, binding, price, image_isbn, special_price, 
      weight,currency_conversion.currency_name, 
      currency_conversion.abbreviation, currency_conversion.conversion_rate 
   from books inner join currency_conversion on currency_conversion.id = 
   books.currency_id where title ILIKE 'People of America' or isbn ILIKE 
   'People of America' or author ILIKE 'People of America') as ab;
```

Second query is:

```
   select distinct * from (select title, author, publisher, isbn, edition, 
   book_type, binding, price, image_isbn, 
    special_price, weight,currency_conversion.currency_name, 
currency_conversion.abbreviation, currency_conversion.conversion_rate from books 
  inner join currency_conversion 
  on currency_conversion.id = books.currency_id where title ilike '%People of America%' or isbn ILIKE '%People of America%' or author ilike '%People of America%') as ab
```

Third query is:

```
select distinct * from (select title, author, publisher, isbn, edition, book_type, binding, price, image_isbn, special_price, 
weight,currency_conversion.currency_name, currency_conversion.abbreviation, currency_conversion.conversion_rate from books inner join currency_conversion 
on currency_conversion.id = books.currency_id where title % 'People of America' or title ilike '%People of America%' 
or isbn ILIKE 'People of America' or author % 'People of America') as ab
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to use the word_similarity function of the pg_trgm modules?

```
select word_similarity('The People of The America', 'People America');

result:
0.681818
```

you can set similarity threshold, for example: >0.5

or you should see the FTS option https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/textsearch.html

Comment: I finally decided to move to elastic search as it is very flexible for this type of searching and will also provide "suggestions search" and "more like this" feature.